# xml to csv through xslt transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I know there are a lot of questions on this, but I am stuck on the problem of converting xml to csv using xslt. I used an example xslt for testing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:key name="field" match="sObject/*" use="name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', name())[1])]">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>

            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="/*/sObject">

            <xsl:variable name="property" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="$property/*">

                <xsl:variable name="value" select="." />
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

             </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>


     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code works well on this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sObjects>
   <sObject>
     <Name>Raagu</Name>
     <BillingStreet>Hoskote</BillingStreet>
   </sObject>
   <sObject>
      <Name>Rajath</Name>
      <BillingStreet>BTM</BillingStreet>
      <age>25</age>
   </sObject>
   <sObject>
      <Name>Sarath</Name>
      <BillingStreet>Murgesh</BillingStreet>
      <location>Bangalore</location>
   </sObject>
</sObjects>
```

The example I found on SO, but could anyone give me a hint on how to process an xml, which has more depth in it? Say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sObjects>
   <sObject>
     <Person>
       <Name>Raagu</Name>
       <BillingStreet>Hoskote</BillingStreet>
     </Person>
     <Country>Germany</Country>
   </sObject>
<sObjects>
```

I will be very grateful for any hint on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's quite easy to write a stylesheet that will transform an XML document **in a given format** to .csv (or anything else). It is very difficult (if even possible) to write one that will handle *any* XML you throw at it.

Comment: BTW, your stylesheet produces an incorrect result even with the first XML: in the third row, "Bangalore" is placed in the "age" column instead of "location".

Comment: **What have you tried?** You've included an unrelated XSLT and said this works on an unrealted input, but I need it to work for a different input. Examine the XSLT you have, *try and write your own* that confroms to your data needs, and then create a new question about a specific problem.

Comment: Hint: Stylesheets are programs. You can't write a program until you've defined the intended behavior. What should the output be for this input example? Do you want to flatten it all into a single set of columns (Raagu, Hoskote, Germany), or do you want to combine the information in some way (name, "Hoskote (Germany)"), or ...

Answer (score 0):

If you can assuming the left nodes always correspond to fields in your CSV output, you should consider redefining the **field** key like-so

```
<xsl:key name="field" match="*[not(*)]" use="local-name()"/>
```

(I am using "local-name()" here so that it can cope with XML that involves namespaces)

Then, define a variable to get the distinct field names

```
<xsl:variable 
     name="fields" 
     select="//*[not(*)][generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', local-name())[1])]" />
```

Here `//*` will look for elements at any depth in the XML. You can then easily iterate over this variable to output the header row as currently. So far so good.

However, despite you saying the current XSLT is working well, it isn't. Because of this line:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$property/*">
```

This is assuming each **sObject** has the same number of child elements (i.e. it has all fields present, and in the right order), which in your XML sample is not the case.

Firstly, I would redefine the **property** variable to be all 'leaf' elements under the current element, at any depth.

```
<xsl:variable name="properties" select=".//*[not(*)]" />
```

Then, you need to iterate over the **fields** variable, not the **properties** element

```
<xsl:for-each select="$fields">
```

The **properties** element is then used to find the element within it that matches the current field name, like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="$properties[local-name()=local-name(current())]"/>
```

Try the following XSLT then

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:key name="field" match="*[not(*)]" use="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="//*[not(*)][generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', local-name())[1])]" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
            <xsl:variable name="properties" select=".//*[not(*)]" />
            <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
                <xsl:value-of select="$properties[local-name()=local-name(current())]"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
             </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should work on both your XML samples. Also note there is not a mention of **sObject** in sight (The assumption being the children of the root element correspond to the records, and the leaf elements correspond to fields)

Do note, the XSLT uses a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to determine the distinct field names. Read about this, and learn it well.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting the correct result with this. I am using Java to process the xml. I was wondering if you could advise on the java code to process xml with this xslt successfuly, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by saying you are not getting the correct result? Are you getting an error? Is nothing being output? Or is CSV being output, but not in the format you want? I tested this at http://www.xslfiddle.net/ and it appears to work. It might help if you edit your question to show the CSV format you actually want. I do not know Java, I am afraid, so if you want help with java code you will probably have to ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I get the following output:
Name,
Raagu,Rajath,Sarath,

Comment: I get the following output: Name, Raagu,Rajath,Sarath, I would like it to be in the following format:Name,Raagu,Hoskote,Name,Rajath,BillingStreet,BTM,age,25.
I use java code to transform the xml: TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform2.xslt"));Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
Could you comment on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alao is that an XSLT 2.0?

Comment: It is XSLT 1.0. Does the XML you are actually using have namespaces, by any chance? If so, I've actually made an edit to my answer to cope with this better.